# Layout an HTML element independent of context

Tags: html, css

I want to free-float a chunk of DOM, that happens to include a `<UL>`, relative to an element, that happens to be in a `<UL>`, and I want the layout of the chunk of DOM to not be a function of its parent. That is as if it was a direct child of the `<body>` element.

HTML

```
<UL><LI>aaa</LI></UL>
<HR>
<UL>
  <li>
    <span class="r">x-<div class="freefloat">
      <UL><LI>aaa</LI></UL>
    </div></span>
  </li>
  <li>hello world</li>
</UL>
```

CSS

```
.r { position: relative; }
.freefloat { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1em; }
```

In the example, the two lists with `aaa` items end up with different bullets. That specific property can be suppressed/overridden, but how can I "reset" *everything* to be as it would be at the top level scope?

https://jsfiddle.net/tfy172x0/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question. It seems like your trying to do something - but you're not telling us what it is. Maybe just explaining the ideal outcome would help.

> I want to free-float a chunk of DOM, that happens to include a , relative to an element, that happens to be in a

OK. But I'm not sure I'd call that free-floating.

This sounds like a drop-down or something - but just really mysterious ; )

> ...how can I "reset" everything to be as it would be at the top level
>   scope?

You can use `initial` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial in this case / but I wouldn't consider it to 'reset everything' - I don't think there is a way to do that. Usually - I'd just reset everything with a meyer reset - and explicitly define the list styles anyway.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.free-willy {
   position: relative;
}

.free-willy ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1em;

  background-color: lightgray;
  padding-right: 1rem;

  list-style: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul class="z">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>

  <li class='free-willy'>
    <span>2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Is this what you want?

UPDATE:

I think we have a few clashes with terminology. You're probably too smart for CSS. haha. Ok, so "as a function of their position" is confusing but I think it helps get to the core of the questions.

There are 2 things happening here.

1. Sound like you are still getting used to the idea of [the 'Cascade'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) in CSS. I know it seems crazy... but you'll have to embrace it. There *are* ways of scoping components so that they do not inherit parent things with more advanced setups / but it's not really worth it.
2. Each browser has a standard set of styles that it imposes on your code. The 'nested' `ul` has a different dot because chrome decided that.

Some things to look at:

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  This will "reset" the CSS (by overriding defaults) to remove - *almost all* styles set by any browser.

that in use: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/v3p1t5b2/

Comment: What I'm building is a drop down (or close enough). -- Maybe the confusion is that I'm assuming (possibly incorrectly) that there are things other than `list-style` that end up styled as a function of their position in tree and would need to be reset. Do elements other than lists have that? Are there CSS classes that apply to everything under them in the tree?

Comment: Added an update! CSS styles are going to cascade down to their child elements. It's not just lists. If you put `color: red` on the body - then everything in the document will be red / until you tell it not to be. So, you might want to think in _components_ and style in smaller scopes.

Comment: Ok, but that's again not really what I want, but because it does too *much*. I don't want to suppress the browser defaults, but rather revert to them. And I'm fine with cascading, I just want to control where the style cascades from independently from where it is placed in the dom tree. --- Now that I think more on it, I suspect the generalized feature of "set CSS parent to cascade from" is more likely to be offered than the special case I was asking for.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would ever want the browser default list styles. Maybe in the middle of an article - or on a 'terms of service' page / but that's beside the point. Almost all the browser defaults are trouble. We always remove all of them. I'd look over https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 - and see if you can use `>` or something - to get what you want. Good luck! : )

Answer (score -1):

```
ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was referring to when I pointed out that "That specific property can be suppressed/overridden".  --- What I'm interested in is how to get every other property of every other type of element to act as if it was at the top level.